# Overland Journey to Thailand via Myanmar 2019

Tags: india, automobiles, thailand, overland

Myanmar and Thailand both have their own permits to allow foreign vehicles to cross or enter on temporary basis and then leave their countries, respectively. These countries do not accept Carnet de Passage as a single document alone. Now If I want to take an Indian Registered 2/4 Wheeler to Thailand via Myanmar and back into India do I need Carnet de Passage (issued from WIAA, Mumbai) compulsory ?